# How to make a organization tree plot by using Python?

Tags: python, plot, charts, tree, visualization

I would like to build an organization chart. Like below:

```
A - B - C
B - C - D
A - E
```

This means A supervises B and B supervises C, C supervises D, and A supervises E. I would like to know if I could build a tree plot by using each employee as a node.

```
A - B - C - D 
|
E
```

some of the codes are as below, I don't know how to apply it to my current human resource data.

```
pip install python-igraph
import igraph
from igraph import Graph, EdgeSeq
nr_vertices = 25
v_label = list(map(str, range(nr_vertices)))
G = Graph.Tree(nr_vertices, 2) # 2 stands for children number
lay = G.layout('rt')

position = {k: lay[k] for k in range(nr_vertices)}
Y = [lay[k][1] for k in range(nr_vertices)]
M = max(Y)

es = EdgeSeq(G) # sequence of edges
E = [e.tuple for e in G.es] # list of edges

L = len(position)
Xn = [position[k][0] for k in range(L)]
Yn = [2*M-position[k][1] for k in range(L)]
Xe = []
Ye = []
for edge in E:
    Xe+=[position[edge[0]][0],position[edge[1]][0], None]
    Ye+=[2*M-position[edge[0]][1],2*M-position[edge[1]][1], None]

labels = v_label

import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=Xe,
               y=Ye,
               mode='lines',
               line=dict(color='rgb(210,210,210)', width=4),
               hoverinfo='none'
               ))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=Xn,
              y=Yn,
              mode='markers',
              name='bla',
              marker=dict(symbol='circle-dot',
                            size=28,
                            color='#6175c1',    #'#DB4551',
                            line=dict(color='rgb(50,50,50)', width=1)
                            ),
              text=labels,
              hoverinfo='text',
              opacity=0.8
              ))

def make_annotations(pos, text, font_size=15, 
font_color='rgb(250,250,250)'):
    L=len(pos)
    if len(text)!=L:
        raise ValueError('The lists pos and text must have the same len')
    annotations = []
    for k in range(L):
        annotations.append(
            dict(
                text=labels[k], # or replace labels with a different list for the text within the circle
            x=pos[k][0], y=2*M-position[k][1],
            xref='x1', yref='y1',
            font=dict(color=font_color, size=font_size),
            showarrow=False)
    )
return annotations

axis = dict(showline=False, # hide axis line, grid, ticklabels and  title
        zeroline=False,
        showgrid=False,
        showticklabels=False,
        )

fig.update_layout(title= 'Tree with Reingold-Tilford Layout',
          annotations=make_annotations(position, v_label),
          font_size=12,
          showlegend=False,
          xaxis=axis,
          yaxis=axis,
          margin=dict(l=40, r=40, b=85, t=100),
          hovermode='closest',
          plot_bgcolor='rgb(248,248,248)'
          )
fig.show()
```

I don't know how the numbers are shown in the circles. Instead, I would like the employees' names shown in the circles. 
Can anyone help?